# OAuth2 flow for same domain website

Tags: oauth-2.0

I am building an OAuth2 API for my program. But I don't know how the flow works for using the same API on the main website for the app? Would I just use the normal authentication route? I think it would seem odd to see that the trusted name app is wanting access to information, when its not a third party.

Comment: I would expect that your client would need to do the normal handshake to get its access token for the API, same as any third party. Can you add a scenario of how you want this to work?